# Unable to save product price for euro in proper way for magento product

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to save a product price for euro.While saving i am keeping price in comma seperated like `price=5,500` that means `price=5.500`

but magento is not taking it as `5.500`

While trying to save price in decimal format like price=5.500 it also doesn't consider

Please help

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Answer (score 0):

magento never save prices  as per the comma separation. try to save with decimal (.) It will save on show of the price on front end can be updated . and show as you want on front end.